# how to get rid of descriptions that are linked to input types?

Tags: 6, input-formats

I've got a question about the descriptions that are linked to input type options.
How do I get rid of it?

I've inherited a site that, for some reason, when I mouse over the options they start twitching as the text adjusts and tries to move to the second line. As a result is a pain to make the PHP selection.
I've seen other drupal sites that have the option without the description, but when I went to "Site configuration > Input formats" I didn't see any way to remove those descripts.

any suggestions or links to documentation would be welcome![image]

Answer (score 2):

The [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module is your friend here, you can use it to remove all or part of the format descriptions/options:

> Better formats is a module to add more flexibility to Drupal's core input format system.
>
> ...
>
> - Set the default format per role.
> - Set the default format per content type.
> - Control allowed formats per content type.
> - **Hide format tips.**
> - **Hide more format tips link.**
> - **Hide format selection for nodes, comments, and blocks seperately, forcing the default to be used.**
>
> ...

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks! this looks promising, I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help!